# Is there a way to get the column usage of a view from multiple databases with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, view, ssms

When I use:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'v_ExampleView'
```

I get the table and columns from the current database but there are tables outside of that database being used in the view. I have read-only access to our data warehouse and I am trying to get information on our views such as what tables they are pulling from and potentially what conditions are being applied. I am using SSMS. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function for this. Don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, it's for compatibility only.

```sql
SELECT ed.*
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.v_ExampleView', 'OBJECT');  --make sure to specify the schema
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It appears I don't have the necessary access to see the results of this query. I got with my DBA and he ran the query and got results whereas mine are blank.

Comment: You will have to talk to your DBA to get access to the correct system data